# Wrapping Text Inside reportlab table from Dataframe

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to get the text inside the table to wrap when I post it to the PDF.

My Code looks like this:

```
def df2table(df):
    table = Table(
        [[Paragraph(col) for col in df.columns]] + (df.values.tolist()),
        style=[
            ("FONTNAME", (0, 0), (-1, 0), "Helvetica-Bold"),
            ("ALIGN", (1, 1), (-1, -1), "LEFT"),
            ("LINEBELOW", (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),
            ("INNERGRID", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
            ("BOX", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
            ("ROWBACKGROUNDS", (0, 0), (-1, -1), [colors.lightgrey, colors.white]),
        ],
        hAlign="LEFT",
        
    )

    return table
```

my output currently looks like this

[image: Output PDF]

My end goal is to wrap the text in the Risk Name of the first table, so that all of the tables are the same width. I am new to making PDFs in Python, if there is a better approach please let me know.

EDIT:  My problem seems to lie in making the Values in the Table a flowable.  I can get the Column Headers to wrap, you can see in my code that they are designated as "Paragraph"...  I cannot designate the table content as a "Paragraph"

Comment: The problem appears to be that I am making the table from a dataframe, so I cannot seem to designate the content as a paragraph. I can get the headers of the columns to wrap, its the data inside the columns that I cannot get to wrap.